# Extract Unicode Hex string using HTML::Element

Tags: html, perl, unicode

I am using `HTML::TreeBuilder` in Perl to extract some text from a html tag. I then use `$tree->look_down` method to get the tags that I want.

However, the text I am returning can be in several different languages including non-latin characters.

If I do the following, I will get the unicode hex string of the characters (such as `&#x652;`) but will also get the html tags (e.g. div, span etc):

```
my $valText = $text[0]->as_HTML();
```

If I do the following, I will get the printed characters only (e.g. in chinese, arabic etc), but not the unicode hex string

```
my $valText = $text[0]->as_text;
```

How is it possible to get the unicode hex string **and** no tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of would be strip away the tags from the result of as_HTML():

```perl
my $valText = $text[0]->as_HTML();
# strip away all the tags
$vatText =~ s/<.*?>//g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to get the module to do something it wasn't designed for, I suggest you use an expression substitution on the string

This program will change the representation of all non-ASCII characters in a string to a hex character entity. I've used `U+0652 ARABIC SUKUN` because that's the example in the question, but as you probably know it's a tiny non-spacing mark so I'm afraid it isn't very visible in the output! (Is that why you wanted to see the hex entity value instead?)

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

my $s = "abc\x{0652}xyz";
say $s;

$s =~ s/([\x{80}-\x{ffff}])/sprintf '&#x%04x;', ord $1/ge;
say $s;
```

#### output

```
abcْxyz
abc&#x0652;xyz
```